# read a file a return word and space python

Tags: python

I want to read a file and return word and space in the file with python.
and i don't want to pass caractere to caractere.

I already used :

```
def openfile(name_file) :
   with open(name_file) as f :
      l = re.split(' ',re.sub('\n',' ',f.read()))
      sentence = []
      for i in l : 
         sentence.append(i)
      print(sentence)
```

input :

```
  Clustalo O(1.2.4) multiple sequence alignement
  
  id_ref     ATGFDFVREF--SFERFSRSFVSRVSVSVRVSFDFVEGREHEHZ
  id_iso     ADEFZRVSDFVSSVDFSVSEFVDCSZF--ZEVVDSVZRVEFDFV
             -------------- ------- -------------  -  ---
```

output on my script :

```
 ['clustal','O(1.2.4)','multiple','sequence','alignement', ect...]
```

expected output :

```
['clustal','','O(1.2.4)','','multiple','','sequence','','alignement',ect...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution for this, but you can do something like this:

```
import re


def openfile(name_file):
    with open(name_file) as f:

        original_list = []
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            li = line.split(' ')
            for item in li:
                if item != '':
                    original_list.append(item.strip('\n'))
                    original_list.append('')

        print(original_list)
```

Output:

```
['clustal', '', 'O(1.2.4)', '', 'multiple', '', 'sequence', '', 'alignement10', '']
```

If you don't need the extra `''` at the end you can simply remove it with

```
original_list.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok but something you should pay attention

first your txt file that includes your characters,

in operating systems, each line ends with \n if you go to next line

but here you don't have any new line character because its a single line

second `re.split` make a list of characters based on pattern you give, so you give it a

pattern including a space character so the string will be splited on spaces

and the output list will not include spaces! so you have two options to make your code work

**Option 1**

if all of your characters in txt file in one line,

replace every space with two space so it will make an empty character string between each character

like this

txt file

```
Clustalo O(1.2.4) multiple sequence alignement
```

code.py

import re

```
def openfile(name_file) :
   with open(name_file, "r") as f :
      l = re.split(' ',re.sub(' ','  ',f.read()))
      for i in l : 
         print('i :', i)
```

output

```
i : Clustalo
i :
i : O(1.2.4)
i :
i : multiple
i :
i : sequence
i :
i : alignement
```

**option 2**

if your txt file is like this

```
Clustalo
O(1.2.4)
multiple
sequence
alignement
```

replace every \n character with double spaces(note: dont include space after each charcter, or make the replacement one space)

code.py

```
import re

def openfile(name_file) :
   with open(name_file, "r") as f :
      l = re.split(' ',re.sub('\n','  ',f.read()))
      for i in l : 
         print('i :', i)
```

output

```
i : Clustalo
i :
i : O(1.2.4)
i :
i : multiple
i :
i : sequence
i :
i : alignement
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a parameter on the end of print

```py
def openfile(name_file) :
   with open(name_file) as f :
      l = re.split(' ',re.sub('\n',' ',f.read()))
      for i in l : 
         print('i :', i, '\ni : ')
```